# Symfony 2.1 form theme for validation errors won't override default

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.1

I tried to override the default error twig template in my symfony 2.1 app with this:

```
#config.yml
twig:
   debug:            %kernel.debug%
   strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
   form:
     resources:
       - 'AAACoreBundle::form_errors.html.twig' 
       - 'AAACoreBundle::form_label.html.twig'
```

And I created form_errors.html.twig in my AAACoreBundle/Resources/views (pretty much a copy/paste from the default one).

```
#form_errors.html.twig
{% block form_errors %}
{% spaceless %}
{% if errors|length > 0 %}
<ul class="validation_errors">
    {% for error in errors %}
    <li>{{
                    error.messagePluralization is null
                        ? error.messageTemplate|trans(error.messageParameters, 'validators')
                        : error.messageTemplate|transchoice(error.messagePluralization, error.messageParameters, 'validators')
    }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_errors %}
```

Unfortunately, only the label template is used. For validation errors I still get the default template.
Strangely enough, when I force this template in my twig form file it works:

```
{% form_theme form with 'AAACoreBundle::form_errors.html.twig' %}
```

Does anybody know what I could check? I can't seem to find the reason for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I don't understand, switching the order did indeed work.

Many thanks to dreipunktnull who suggested this!